# Mutt abook empty query

Tags: email, mutt

I am running `mutt` as my email client, with `abook` to manage addresses.

I understand that to send a query to `abook` I can use `Q`, with the relevant part of my `muttrc` being:

```
set query_command = "abook --mutt-query '%s'"
```

But this requires me to type some query, which will shorten my address list. Often I want to browse through my entire address book to find the relevant recipients, especially if I can't remember their name at first.

**Is there a way to send an empty query to `abook`, to display all of my contacts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `""` as an argument. Press <kbd>Q</kbd> in `mutt` and then just enter `""` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. You can also test it in a command line ( I added 2 public addresses for a test):

```
$ abook --mutt-query ""

help-gnu-emacs-bounces@gnu.org  help-gnu-emacs-bounces@gnu.org
auth@gmane.org  Gmane Autoauthorizer
```

Alternatively you can use aliases. Set this in your `.muttrc`:

```
set alias_file=~/.mutt-alias
source ~/.mutt-alias
```

Now press <kbd>a</kbd> inside `mutt` to run `create-alias` function. You can then display a list of all of your  aliases by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> when choosing a recipient.